# The limit of $(1+\frac1x)^x$ as $x\to\infty$

Tags: limits, constants

I was experimenting with a graphing calculator to check
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac1x)^x=e$$
I plotted the graph of $y=(1+\frac1x)^x$, and I was surprised when I zoomed out enough.
[image: Graph of $y=(1+\frac1x)^x$]
It is oscillating until it reaches $x=9\times 10^{15}$, where $y$ becomes $1$ and stays there afterwards. How could we explain this?

Comment: Uh... that's not right.  What program did you use for this?

Comment: Something went wrong here, it should not do that. Without seeing your code, I can't really help. If you are using arrays, perhaps switch to a while loop to fix the continuity.

Comment: What you have there are floating point errors...

Comment: @user361424 I used Geogebra. I got the same result in Desmos on my android phone, too.

Comment: Unfortunately, schools (except for technical university studies) don't really stress enough that calculators and computers use finite precision approximation for real numbers (~16 decimal places, which isn't that much), and without taking this into account, things go wrong when you use extreme numerical values (using big exponents, subtracting very similar numbers, adding very different numbers). There are exceptions (specialized software, which doesn't use builting floating point numbers), but generally you have to be aware of this limitation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Very easily: your calculator is using double-precision floating-point arithmetic.

So the values of $1+\dfrac1x$ are truncated to $53$ bits and the larger $x$, the more significant bits are lost. You are actually computing $(1+\epsilon)^x$ where $\epsilon$ is a truncation of $\dfrac1x$ to a multiple of $2^{-53}$. In the intervals such that $\epsilon$ remains constant, you get an exponential curve.

When you exceed $x=2^{53}\approx9.0072\times10^{15}$, then $\epsilon=0$.

---

As you can verify, the previous jumps occur precisely at

$$\epsilon=3\cdot2^{-53}\to x\approx3.0024\times10^{15},$$

$$\epsilon=6\cdot2^{-53}\to x\approx1.5012\times10^{15},$$
and probably
$$\epsilon=7\cdot2^{-53}\to x\approx1.2867\times10^{15}.$$

The particular integers that appear depend on the details of the division algorithm used (with possible guard bits and rounding).

---

For the computation of the powers, logarithms are used, yielding the formula

$$\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\approx e^{x\ln(1+\epsilon)}.$$

As $\ln(1+\epsilon)\approx\epsilon$ in theory, we can expect that $\ln(1+\epsilon)$ is evaluated like $\eta$, a value close to $\epsilon$, but not necessarily a simple multiple (also because of the inner details of the algorithm). At the jump points, $x=1/\epsilon$ and the function value is $e^{\eta/\epsilon}$.

This explains why the largest value is exactly $e^2=7.3890\cdots$, due to $\epsilon=2^{-53}$ and $\eta=2\cdot2^{-53}$.

The two values at $\epsilon=3\cdot2^{-53}$ must be exactly $e^{2/3}$ and $e^{4/3}$, corresponding to $\eta=2\cdot2^{-53}$ and $4\cdot2^{-53}$ respectively.

The values at $\epsilon=6\cdot2^{-53}$ can be conjectured to be $e^{19/24}$ and $2^{29/24}$ (from $\eta=4.75\cdot2^{-53}$ and $7.25\cdot2^{-53}$), but this is less sure.

---

Below is a *qualitative* simulation of this phenomenon with the formula

$$e^{\frac x{64}\left[\frac{64}x\right]}$$ where the brackets denote a rounding operation.

[image]

The "envelope" curves are the exponentials $e^{1\pm x/128}$.

Comment: You said $\epsilon$ is a truncation of $1+\frac1x$ to a multiple of $2^{-53}$. I am a little confused.  Shouldn't it be a truncation of $\frac1x$?

Comment: @W.Zhu: you are quite right, thank you for pointing this. Fixing.

Comment: @Arthur: ooops, my fingers typed integer while my mind was thinking fp.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a floating point error, coming from the fact that inside computers, numbers are constantly being rounded to some fixed number of significant digits. Basically, once $x$ becomes large enough, $\frac1x$ becomes really small, and the program cannot tell the difference between $1 + \frac1x$ and $1+\frac1{x+d}$ for relatively small $d$. That means that for an entire interval, $1 + \frac1x$ gets rounded to some fixed $1+\frac1{x_0}$, and then exponentiated. You can note that on each of the separate continuous parts, the function looks very much like $a^x$ would for some constant $a$.

After $9\cdot 10^{15}$, the program just gives up completely, says "as far as I'm concerned, $1 + \frac1x = 1$" and your function becomes constant.